# How to make most basic router-tab on Vue3?

Tags: tabs, vue-component, router, vuejs3

I using vue3. I need to router-tabs likes [vue-router-tab](https://bhuh12.github.io/vue-router-tab/guide/essentials/#import-routertab).
I tried to use vue-router-tab on Vue3, but its changelog shows that it only works with Vue2.
So I want to make a router tab myself. But I don't know how to make it.
Please tell me how to make the most basic router-tab.

Answer (score 0):

You want to rely on Vue's `<slot>` method. There are multiple ways of doing it from there.

There's a LearnVue that will help you learn how to do it: https://learnvue.co/tutorials/vue-reusable-tabs-component

Comment: this is relevant only for vue 2, because in vue 3 the $children property has been removed